# Alert box to accept cookies in a web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3, alert

I wanna know how to put a .js code in a button that it's in a bootstrap alert that when the user clicked accept, the alert box no appear again.

Thanks a lot.

---

This is the code that I have, but doesn't work.

JS:

```js
 $(".btn_cerrar").on({
     click: function(){
      location.reload(
      $(".pb-element-alert").hidden();
        });  
    });
```

```html
<div id="modal">
<p style="text-align: center;">Este sitio web emplea cookies para ofrecerle un servicio más</p>
<p> personalizado.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Si continúa navegando entenderemos que acepta nuestra</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a title="Politicas" href="images/eventos/POLITICA_DE_TRATAMIENTOS_DE_DATOS.pdf" target="_blank"><strong>Políticas de tratamiento de la información</strong></a> de nuestro sitio web.</p>
<button class=" btn_cerrar btn pull-right btn-success" type="button" data-dismiss="alert"> Aceptar</button></div>
```

HTML:

`

Este sitio web emplea cookies para ofrecerle un servicio más

personalizado.

Si continúa navegando entenderemos que acepta nuestra

**Políticas de tratamiento de la información** de nuestro sitio web.

Aceptar
`

Comment: You have syntax errors and I don't understand what you want to happen on button click exactly?

Comment: No, I don't know why doesn't work, that's the isssue.

Comment: I can see that you have syntax errors. I can help you correct them if you tell me (just explain with plain words) what do you want to happen when the user clicks the button.

Comment: I want the website don't show again the bootstrap alert, after to clicked accept.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly is the alert you are talking about since it is not shown in your html.

The correct syntax of your script should be that:

```
$(".btn_cerrar").on('click', function(){
    // Do what you want.
});
```

Now if the element you want hide can be selected from the selector `$(".pb-element-alert")` you mention in your question then you can use this:

```
$(".pb-element-alert").hide();
```

All of it together would be:

```
$(".btn_cerrar").on('click', function(){
    $(".pb-element-alert").hide();
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    bool isBtnClicked = sessionStorage.getItem('buttonClicked') == true;

    if(isBtnClicked){
        $(".pb-element-alert").hide();
    }
});

$(".btn_cerrar").on('click', function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('buttonClicked', true);
  $(".pb-element-alert").hide();
});
```

Comment: yes that's is, but if I refresh the navigator, the alert shows it again.

Comment: What do you mean with "I refresh the navigator"? You refresh the page?

Comment: My friend If I understand correctly you want to hold some kind of state. This information has to be saved somewhere. You can use localstorage or sessionstorage for client side storage, or typical backend storage (DB). However I don't know what do you want to achieve and I think you are overcomplicating your case. And answers of type "something like that" are really annoying when I am trying to help you.

Comment: yes,  I need the people just see the alert one time, I try to looking for a cookies.get() function, or something like that.

When the user click in the accept button, never show again the alert

Comment: My friend, I said  "something like that" because I can't remember the function that I used.

I'm trying with some codes, but I can't do it.

Sorry if you understand another something.

Comment: I want to show you where I have the issue: http://www.tecnomultimedia.com.mx/
thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer using the sessionStorage to hold the state. When a button click occures you will save in the session storage the necessairy info. When you get into the page again in the document ready the browser will check if there is a true value inside the button click key and if there is it will hide the button again.

Comment: My friend, thanks a lot, I'll try it, thank you for you patience.